# Replacing a loop with 2 commits to 2 tables with a single aggregate commit?

Tags: sql, db2, cobol

(Using DB2)
I have a bit of code that does 2 commits (to 2 tables) per row, that I would like to change to once per 25 rows or something similar.
Here is the basic code:

```
    (Code that finds MG-LOCATOR-NBR and MG-PG-NBR here)
    MOVE MG-LOCATOR-NBR  TO MT-LOCATOR-NBR
    MOVE MG-PG-NBR       TO MT-PG-NBR        
    SET IOC1-DELETE-MG TO TRUE
       PERFORM IOC1-IO
       EXEC SQL
            COMMIT
       END-EXEC
       SET IOC1-DELETE-MT TO TRUE
       PERFORM IOC1-IO
       EXEC SQL
            COMMIT
       END-EXEC
```

If it was for one commit/table only, I think this would work:

```
       ADD 1 TO WS-REC-COUNT
       IF WS-REC-COUNT = 25
           MOVE ZERO TO WS-REC-COUNT
           EXEC SQL COMMIT END-EXEC
       END-IF

       (And a final COMMIT in the End-of-Job Method to cover the ending)
```

But Im confused on how to do with calling 2 different tables at once. Any suggestions?

Edit: The SQL for the deletes are pretty straightforward:

```
        ;IOC1-DEL-MG  SECTION .
        EXEC SQL DELETE FROM VMG
           WHERE LOCATOR_NBR     = :MG-LOCATOR-NB
               AND PG_NBR        = :MG-PG-NBR
        END-EXEC
                    IF SQLCODE = 0
           SET ;IOC1-OK           TO TRUE
        ELSE IF SQLCODE = +100
           SET ;IOC1-NO-DATA      TO TRUE
        END-IF
        DISPLAY 'DELETE MG' SQLCODE

        ;IOC1-DEL-MT  SECTION .
        EXEC SQL DELETE FROM VMT
           WHERE LOCATOR_NBR     = :MT-LOCATOR-NB
               AND PG_NBR        = :MT-PG-NBR
        END-EXEC
                    IF SQLCODE = 0
           SET ;IOC1-OK           TO TRUE
        ELSE IF SQLCODE = +100
           SET ;IOC1-NO-DATA      TO TRUE
        END-IF
        DISPLAY 'DELETE MT' SQLCODE
```

Comment: You show a fragment of COBOL code and no SQL except for COMMIT, but you don't show what PERFORM IOC1-IO is doing in terms of SQL. Also, there is no meaning to "..calling 2 different tables", so you should rephrase the question.

Comment: Added SQL code.

Comment: by "calling 2 different tables at once", do you mean "perform a   searched-delete statement on table VMG and then another searched-delete on table VMT *in the same database transaction* ?  If that is what you mean, then that is valid and common. However, you become responsible for any concurrency issues that may arise by reducing the commit-count.  (We cannot tell from your code how many rows each DELETE will act on, because we cannot see your data-model).

Comment: For VMG the database has only the 2 listed primary keys. For VMT, there is a third primary key, so there will be multiple row deletes. Im just looking for an example on how to do a commit only once every 25 times the SQLs are executed instead of every time.

Comment: Recommended practice in my old IT shop was to obtain a commit interval from a runtime parameter.  This way we could adjust for concurrency issues on the fly.

Comment: If each delete statement could delete several rows, consider different logic. If SQLCODE is zero, Retrieve the number of rows affected by each delete statement (get diagnostics..or use SQLCA.) and use that value to increment your counting variable per delete. Also consider having the commit-count parameterised per another comment.

Comment: Um, if the only thing touching the DB is the `DELETE` statements, you may as well make them auto-commit.  If anything else is going on, it may be more complicated than this (would need more details first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB2 is not doing a commit per table.  When you call commit like that, you commit all work since the last commit.

So if you went to one commit, every 25 iterations, or after every 50 deletes, that will work.

Be aware, if your program AbEnds while it is deleting row 36, then you will need to account for going back and cleaning up those rows when you restart.